# Merge two columns of a table in excel

Tags: excel

I want to merge 2 columns of a table in excel.

In excel if we want to merge two cells then there is an option called **Merge & Center** which id the same thing I want.

But when I create a tbale then select two columns and try to apply the same but in that case **Merge & center** button is disables. Is there any way in excel to merge two columns of a table.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not a button to do that. However, you can concatenate the two columns to third column and use that instead.

Comment: That also works and sounds easier to do than my suggestion, a formula on a third column will do the trick.

Comment: I want one column whose width is equal to 2 columns

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is... Resizing columns in Excel is piece of cake, just put the cursor in the space after the column header, click and drag.

Answer (score 1):

You may have data on both cells and thats why that wont work, merge cells only work with empty cells and other cell (with data or empty too).

I'll create a macro to do the repetitive work.